# MySQL decimal column SUM

Tags: mysql, sum, decimal, mysql-5.7, decimal-point

I am using MySQL 5.7.22. I have decimal columns in my table. Decimal column values like `31355,20`,`30710,00`.
In the query when I get sum two values of the column, the result is without comma. But I need digits after comma. How can I do this? What is the problem?

Comment: Post the table structure and the query.

Comment: I wonder if there is a "locale" setting somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql float use dot `.` instead of a comma, but if you want to get comma you can try to convert your result to string the use `REPLACE` function.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE T(col DECIMAL(5, 2));

INSERT INTO T VALUES (11.22)
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select REPLACE(cast(col as CHAR(50)),'.',',') 
from T;

| REPLACE(cast(col as CHAR(50)),'.',',') |
| -------------------------------------- |
| 11,22                                  |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/orjD5ou8MsmEgsJGhw2T3h/0)

Comment: indeed + 1 but MySQL REPLACE function works like a charm on DECIMAL data you don't have to use CAST because of MySQL's autocasting.. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/orjD5ou8MsmEgsJGhw2T3h/1